# How can I get rid of the Title Bar of a Window when taking a screenshot of it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, screenshot

So right now I am taking a screenshot of an application by doing this:

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height))
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top), new Point(0, 0), Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size);
    bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Neoray\Desktop\Test.png", ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

This works fine enough but the problem is that I need to get rid of the Title Bar that is in there (doesn't matter if its afterwards by altering the image or when taking the screenshot itself).

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: You mean, you're taking a screenshot of the entire screen and the application happens to be maximized (and can be maximized) or is it your application your're taking pictures of?

Comment: @Jimi i want to take a screenshot of an application (not my windows form app) that is maximized. (it will always be so there is no need to take resizing into consideration).

Comment: The size is not important. Do you need the `ClientArea` of this Window (no Borders) or the complete Window (including the borders) but without the `Caption` (Title Bar)?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that not all Windows have an actual Caption. Applications that use some Theme to customize their interface, don't have a *real* Caption (Firefox, for example, doesn't have one, in *WinForms* language). In this case, there's no way to know which is the size of the makeshift Caption. It could be the *standard* size (OS settings), or something completly different (the MS Office programs are another example, but a number of WPF themed/skinned apps share this feature. Some WinForms apps, too). In this case, you'll have to adapt the Window rectangle to a specific size.

Comment: @Jimi whichever is the easiest to do. The goal is just to get rid of the title bar.

Comment: Yes, but, what kind of application is this? Does it have a standard *Title Bar* or does it looks like the applications I mentioned?

Comment: @Jimi heres a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/gbMjZFl.jpg theres only a title bar, no other borders or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this method will return the `ClientArea` of a Process Window, excluding the `Caption` (`Title Bar`) only when the Window actually has a `Caption`. Not all applications do (in *WinForms* sense).
Also, no guarantee whatsoever that it can work with a maximized Window which is rendered using DirectX APIs.
In this case, it would be necessary to implement a completely different method.
Anyway, it should work correctly with the sample image you're showing.

---

The overloaded main method accepts both a Process Name and Process ID.

**Parameters**:

**`string processName`** or **`int processId`**:
Specify the process friendly Name (the one shown in Task Manager, it's not case sensitive) or the Process Id (also available in Task Manager).
It can be easily modified to also accept the Window Title.

**`bool clientAreaOnly`**:
Switch. Lets you specify whether you want a screenshot of the `ClientArea` section only or the whole Windows bounds.

**`float dpi`**:
You can define the Dpi resolution of the final `Bitmap`.

**Sample usage**:

- Takes a screenshot of the Main Window of a process with Name `[Some Process Name]`
- Instructs to only consider the `ClientArea` (the Window `Caption` and `Borders` will be excluded)
- Specifies that the `Bitmap` resolution should be `120Dpi`
- Saves a `Bitmap` in `PNG` format, named `ScreenShot.png`, in `[Some Path]`

  ```
  using (var bitmap = ProcessWindowScreenshot("[Some Process Name]", true, 120)) {
      bitmap.Save(@"[Some Path]\ScreenShot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
  }
  ```

**Sample procedure**:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public Bitmap ProcessWindowScreenshot(string processName, bool clientAreaOnly, float dpi)  {
    using (var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
                                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero))  {
        if (process == null) return null;
        return GetProcessWindowScreenshot(GetProcessWindowRect(process.Id, clientAreaOnly), dpi);
    }
}

public Bitmap ProcessWindowScreenshot(int processId, bool clientAreaOnly, float dpi)  {
    return GetProcessWindowScreenshot(GetProcessWindowRect(processId, clientAreaOnly), dpi);
}

private Bitmap GetProcessWindowScreenshot(Rectangle window, float dpi)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(window.Width, window.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    bitmap.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.CopyFromScreen(window.Location, Point.Empty, window.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return bitmap;
    };
}

private Rectangle GetProcessWindowRect(int processId, bool isClientArea)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainWindowHandle;
    if (isClientArea) {
        return GetWindowClientRectangle(hWnd);
    }
    else {
        return GetWindowRectangle(hWnd);
    }
}
```

**Windows API declarations and helpers methods**:

```
[UIPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Action = SecurityAction.Demand, Window = UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows)]
public static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr handle)  {
    NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(handle, out RECT rect);
    return rect.ToRectangle();
}

[UIPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Action = SecurityAction.Demand, Window = UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows)]
public static Rectangle GetWindowClientRectangle(IntPtr handle)  {
    NativeMethods.GetClientRect(handle, out RECT rect);
    NativeMethods.ClientToScreen(handle, out POINT point);
    return rect.ToRectangleOffset(point);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;

    public Rectangle ToRectangle() => Rectangle.FromLTRB(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
    public Rectangle ToRectangleOffset(POINT p) => Rectangle.FromLTRB(p.x, p.y, Right + p.x, Bottom + p.y);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, out POINT point);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);
}
```